# Getting ZERO RESULTS from Google Geocode API for a valid residential address

Tags: google-apps-script, google-geocoding-api

I am performing the following geocode api call in a google script function, the address is a residential address (not a business address), it is a valid address when searched in google maps.

Objective: Geocode residential address: 64 Stopford Road, HOVE 5048

Problem: The query below results in a "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS" response

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=64StopfordRoadHOVE5048&key=API_KEY
```

response:

> "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"

Comment: Did you specify your `API_KEY` ?

Comment: Please add a brief description to of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask]. Also add a [mcve].

Comment: @Marios Yes of course! :) I haven't posted it for obvious security reasons.

Comment: @Roggie can you try this : `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=64+Stopford+Road,+HOVE+5048&key=API_KEY`

Comment: @Marios Yes that has worked. I have a code line that was cleaning-up the address and removing spaces `address.replace(/\s/g, " ")`, which means I will need to change and replace spaces with a `+` like this `address.replace(/\s/g, "+")`

Comment: @Roggie sure, but you need to remove the extra comma `,` in the url :)

Comment: @Roggie yes I overlooked it. Glad it solved your issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=64+Stopford+Road+HOVE+5048&key=API_KEY`

Please have a look at the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/overview).